# Java - How can i build contingency into service layer calling web service

Tags: java, web-services, spring

I have a service layer which is calling a webservice. The number of requests generated by the service layer could potentially be very large and i want to build in some contingency in case the volume of requests becomes to much for the web service to handle. I know i can add some exception handling which can tell if the request failed or not however i don't want to keep hitting the service if its down or struggling to handle the requests.

How can i tell my service layer to stop making calls when the service is unavailable and then resume once its active again? I know this can be done manually using a file containing a flag which the service would check before making a call to the webservice. This flag could then be updated whenever the server goes dowm, however i would prefer something automatic.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easily could be done with [interceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/support/interceptor/ClientInterceptor.html#handleRequest%28org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext%29). Just make your own interceptor and implement the logic in here.

Comment: can you expand more on that suggestion? Would the interceptor send the request and/or check the service was still available?

Comment: @linuxlewis Read the documentation by the link above. If you return `false` from the interceptor, the request to the service will be blocked. So, you should define your understanding of `service available` notion and check it in the interceptor.